# generating <li> elements in php

Tags: php, html, html-lists

This should be relatively straightforward but none of the solutions I've found here or elsewhere work at all.

I'm trying to display a table containing all the elements of a list of brands. I added two manually (Adidas and Nike) just to test the display, and these show correctly. I then tried to generate a list using an array of brands (the array brandList has two items, id and name). The output is garbage.

```
<ul class="brand-list">
    <li><a href="#">Adidas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
    <?php
        foreach ($brandList as $item) {
           $text = '<li><a href="#">'.$item[1].'</a></li>';
           echo("$text\n");
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

expected output:

```
 Adidas
 Nike
 Puma
 Asics
```

actual output

```
Adidas
Nike
'.$item[1].''; echo("$text\n"); } ?>
```

I've tried formatting a dozen different ways (with single and double-quotes, backslashes etc.) but it always just displays half of the line of code instead of the variable. I know it's something simple, but I've spent too much time messing with it for no result.

Comment: `foreach $brandList as $item` is not valid

Comment: You need to use proper syntax for `foreach` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: You also might want to _start/open_ your closing `</li>` somewhere

Comment: Are you certain your page gets parsed by PHP?! Do you have a webserver running with PHP enabled? Is your file extension `.php`?

Comment: @brombeer and Cbroe you're right, I had it in, then took it out and forgot to add it. But it makes no difference. Updated the code sample
file is .html but with php tags. PHP is enabled and running on the server

Comment: `.html` files usually don't get parsed by PHP, rename it to `.php` and try again, code looks ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot is wrong with your snippet and frankly I am not surprise it doesn't work.

1. You are using the wrong syntax in your `foreach` loop.
2. The `<li></li>` you are creating has no opening tag just an anchor tag `<a></a>` and a closing list item tag `</li>`.
3. `$test` is a variable with quotes in it, using quotation marks around it during `echo` is just wrong as the `"` in your `href` will close the first quote around the variable outputting others as a string rather than HTML tags.
4. Though not so important but ditch the `\n` character. Your browser will render the list in block format with or without it.

Change your snippet to look like this instead

```
<ul class="brand-list">
    <li><a href="#">Adidas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
    <?php
        foreach($brandList as $item) {
    ?>
           <li><a href="#"><?=$item[1]?></a></li>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

If you prefer your current syntax then change it to this

```
<ul class="brand-list">
    <li><a href="#">Adidas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
    <?php
        foreach($brandList as $item) {
           $text = '<li><a href="#">'.$item[1].'</a></li>';
           echo($text);
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your 3. is not a problem. Adding/keeping "\n" will also render the source code fine, not just the rendered HTML

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to let PHP generate the HTML instead of echoing the string. I think that's more clear than echoing.

```php
<ul class="brand-list">
    <li><a href="#">Adidas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
    <?php
        foreach ($brandList as $item) {
    ?>
        <li><a href="#"><?=$item[1]?></a></li>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you have missed starting li tag in side the loop.
Please check this for your solution.

```
<ul class="brand-list">
<li><a href="#">Adidas</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
<?php
   $text="";
   foreach ($brandList as $item){
       $text .= '<li><a href="#">'.$item[1].'</a></li>';
      
    }
    echo($text);
?>
```